# how to use machine learning or network analysis to prevent contagious disease

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling

I would like to share a question about my research. I have data about networking of a contagious disease.

I have 60 pigs, and I have the contact time with others pigs of each individual in 28 study day. So the structure of data would be

```
Day         ID     Network_friend (s)     Network_time (s)
1            1      200                       20000
1            2      300                       3000
.
.
.
```

Those 60 pigs are in similar age and body condition so there is not too much variety among the sample.

I am wondering if there is a way to predict the individuals who will get sick in 2 days to prevent the spread of the disease. Should I use any network analysis for it?

I appreciate any replies!

Thank you!

Comment: The relevant field of study is called _epidemiology_. [Study their models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_modelling_of_infectious_disease). Good luck!